# I need a ternary operator in Java that assigns two variables if the condition is true

Tags: java, ternary

I have seen that one can use multiple ternary conditions, but haven't found a way to assign two variables if a single condition is true. This is the method I'm trying to write:

```
    int[] chkNext(int mnd, int y) {  
        int[] date = new int[2];  
        mnd = 12 ? mnd = 1, y++ : mnd++; // returns the following: "error: : expected"
        date[0] = mnd, date[1] = y;  
        return date;  
    }
```

Comment: I think you can't - just use `if`.

Comment: [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html) has a rule called *avoid inline conditionals*. *Rationale: Some developers find inline conditionals hard to read, so their company's coding standards forbids them.* I don't agree with this rule all the times, but I'm avoiding them anyway. Adding commas or even trying to return multiple values, will get you points in an obfuscated code context, but not in real programming. It's a good thing to be concise, but not at the expense of readability.

Comment: @stivlo: another bad example I found in real world code:
x=(y!=null?(y.getF()!=null?BigDecimal.valueOf(y.getF()):null):null)
I suppose to avoid atrocities like that the Checkstyle rule exists...

Answer (score 8):

Just use an `if` statement.

```
if (mnd == 12) {
//      ^^  very important
  mnd = 1;
  y++;
} else {
  mnd++;
}
```

And this:

```
date[0] = mnd, date[1] = y;
```

Would be better as:

```
date[0] = mnd; date[1] = y;
```

Don't use a comma operator if you don't really need it.

Comment: +1 for sound advice. You don't get extra credit for making your code shorter. On the contrary, cleaner/more readable code is always appreciated.

Comment: Eh, getting late. Thank you so much for pointing out the bleeding obvious yet sensible choice.

Comment: There isn't a comma operator in Java. (Although, if you like bad code you can declare multiple variables in a single declaration using commas.)

Answer (score -3):

The construct of ternary operator is wrong as there should be condition before '?'. As Mat suggested better option is using if statement.

Ternary can be generally used for simple statements like

```
boolean isEven = (n!=0 && n%2 == 0) ? true : false;
```

Comment: this is really bad practice, you don't need a ternary operator at all to return true of false! Just `boolean isEven = (n != 0 && n % 2 == 0);` is enough.

Comment: I was thinking of some example and just got it. I accept for boolean assignment it is not required.

Comment: (Why the check for `n!=0` if you are then going for `n%2 == 0`?)